# Is it possible to independently customize "Chapter 1" and/or "Appendix A" in chapter heading, page header and TOC?

Tags: header-footer, chapters, titles, appendices, custom

Here is a MWE (with the basic packages I'm using) of what I would like to customize:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twosides,openany,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\bf\sffamily{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\sffamily{\leftmark}}
}

\usepackage[bf,sf]{titlesec} 
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}    
    
\tableofcontents
    
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{main}
    
\chapter{One}
\section{One.one}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{One.two}
\lipsum[8-9]

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Two}
\section{Two.one}
\lipsum[10-19]
\section{Two.two}
\lipsum[19-25]  
\end{appendices}    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Hereafter I show the results of the code above.

Headings of the chapter and names of sections, below:
[image]

Headers on even pages, below:
[image]

TOC, below:
[image]

As an instance of what I'm interested in, I have just one Appendix, so I don't need it to be called "Appendix A", because there is no "Appendix B". I'd like to reach the following level of customization:

1. In the chapter heading I would like it to be called "Appendix" (without the "numbering" letter A); however, within the chapter (sections, subsections, equations, etc.), I would like it to be represented by a single letter, let's say "Ã";
2. In the header, I would like it to be called in a different way, lat's say "App.", while keeping the same header style as before (in my case, capitalized sans serif, see second figure above);
3. In the toc I would like it to be called by a further different name, let's say "Appen."

Now, by copying and pasting excerpts from solutions to other problems, I was "able" to somewhat obtain (1) and (2) (see Figs after the MWE below); I have no idea on how to obtain (3), and my code is halfway between pathetic and horrible, MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twosides,openany,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\bf\sffamily{\rightmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\small\sffamily{\leftmark}}
}

\usepackage[bf,sf]{titlesec} 
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}    
    
\tableofcontents
    
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{main}
    
\chapter{One}
\section{One.one}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{One.two}
\lipsum[8-9]

\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{APP.\quad{TWO}}{}}
\makeatother
\chapter{Two}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\~{A}}
\section{Two.one}
\lipsum[10-19]
\section{Two.two}
\lipsum[19-25]  
\end{appendices}    
    
    
\end{document}
```

Hereafter I show the results of the terrible code above.

"Succesesful" customization of chapter heading and sectioning (to this end, I manually adjusted the verical spacing between "Appendix" and the appendix title), below:
[image]

"Succesesful" customization of headers (to this end, I manually modified the chaptermark, and manually adjusted the horizontal spacing between "App." and its name, put by hand), below:
[image]

TOC is still using the "number" "A":
[image]

So the question is: how should it be done properly?, or at least less improperly?

PS: I tried my best to avoid a duplicate question; I read a lot of different questions; many are very close to this one, but none of them is precisely what I would like to achieve; most likely what I want is not that complicated, and can be obtained by simply adjusting one of those answers, but I'm afraid I'm not skilled enough.